# PWM Signals not generating correctly on stm32 f767zit

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f7, stm32f1

I am working with an stm32 f767zit and I am trying to generate PWM signals to control servos, but they are not generating correctly. I followedd the tutorial from here [Deep Blue Embedded](https://deepbluembedded.com/stm32-servo-motor-control-with-pwm-servo-library-examples-code/) and was able to generate the PWM signals just fine on an stm32 f103rb, but I switched to the f767zit because I needed more PWM outputs. I have already looked at the HAL documentation and for both and compared them and as far as I can tell there are not any differences in how the pwm signals should be generated.

I have done several projects with the stm32 boards but I am still sort of a noob. I have looked for many hours for a solution but I can not find one. Sorry if this is actually just something simple and basic that I am missing.

Here are screen shots of the pwm outputs. as you can see the f103rb generates them normally, sguare waves at 50hz and 3.3v peaks. The pwm signals on the f767 are made up of lots of spikes and have peaks  at 10mV. Although, they do seem to be generating at the correct pulse length

[PWM Output of f103rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y1AO.png)

[PWM Output of f767](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUruW.png)

In my code all I am trying to do is initalize the servos and the set them to a positon. There are 12 servos and they are using timers 1-4. The specific channels and pins can be seen in the Servo configuration code. My main code initializes all of the perifrials and then calls `initServos()` which calls `SERVO_init()` for each servo in `SERVO_CfgParam`. Then my main loop calls `SERVO_moveto()`. I am only moving one servo in the main code but I have tested every pin that I am using and get the same results.

I used the same meathod and code for controlling 3 servos on my f013rb without any problems. I cannot figure out what difference there is on the f767zit.

**Main Code**

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_TIM4_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  initServos();
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

    SERVO_MoveTo(11,90);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

**Servo configuration.**

```c
typedef struct
{
    GPIO_TypeDef * SERVO_GPIO;
    uint16_t       SERVO_PIN;
    TIM_TypeDef*   TIM_Instance;
    uint32_t*      TIM_CCRx;
    uint32_t       PWM_TIM_CH;
    uint32_t       TIM_CLK;
    float          MinPulse;
    float          MaxPulse;
}SERVO_CfgType;

const SERVO_CfgType SERVO_CfgParam[SERVO_NUM] =
{
    // Servo Motor 1 Configurations
    {
        GPIOE,
        GPIO_PIN_9,
        TIM1,
        &TIM1->CCR1,
        TIM_CHANNEL_1,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
    // Servo Motor 2 Configurations
    {
        GPIOE,
        GPIO_PIN_11,
        TIM1,
        &TIM1->CCR2,
        TIM_CHANNEL_2,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
    // Servo Motor 3 Configurations
    {
        GPIOE,
        GPIO_PIN_13,
        TIM1,
        &TIM1->CCR3,
        TIM_CHANNEL_3,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
    // Servo Motor 4 Configurations
    {
        GPIOE,
        GPIO_PIN_14,
        TIM1,
        &TIM1->CCR4,
        TIM_CHANNEL_4,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
    // Servo Motor 5 Configurations
    {
        GPIOA,
        GPIO_PIN_15,
        TIM2,
        &TIM2->CCR1,
        TIM_CHANNEL_1,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
    // Servo Motor 6 Configurations
    {
        GPIOB,
        GPIO_PIN_10,
        TIM2,
        &TIM2->CCR2,
        TIM_CHANNEL_3,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
    // Servo Motor 7 Configurations
    {
        GPIOB,
        GPIO_PIN_11,
        TIM2,
        &TIM2->CCR4,
        TIM_CHANNEL_4,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
    // Servo Motor 8 Configurations
    {
        GPIOC,
        GPIO_PIN_6,
        TIM3,
        &TIM3->CCR1,
        TIM_CHANNEL_1,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
    // Servo Motor 9 Configurations
    {
        GPIOC,
        GPIO_PIN_7,
        TIM3,
        &TIM3->CCR2,
        TIM_CHANNEL_2,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
// Servo Motor 10 Configurations
    {
        GPIOC,
        GPIO_PIN_8,
        TIM3,
        &TIM3->CCR3,
        TIM_CHANNEL_3,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
    // Servo Motor 11 Configurations
    {
        GPIOC,
        GPIO_PIN_9,
        TIM3,
        &TIM3->CCR4,
        TIM_CHANNEL_4,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    },
// Servo Motor 12 Configurations
    {
        GPIOB,
        GPIO_PIN_6,
        TIM4,
        &TIM4->CCR1,
        TIM_CHANNEL_1,
        72000000,
        0.65,
        2.3
    }
};
```

**Servo initialization function**

```c
void SERVO_Init(uint16_t au16_SERVO_Instance)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
    TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
    TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
    TIM_HandleTypeDef htim;
    uint32_t PSC_Value = 0;
    uint32_t ARR_Value = 0;
    //DWT_Delay_Init();

    /*--------[ Configure The Servo PWM GPIO Pin ]-------*/

    if(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].SERVO_GPIO == GPIOA)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    }
    else if(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].SERVO_GPIO == GPIOB)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    }
    else if(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].SERVO_GPIO == GPIOC)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    }
    else if(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].SERVO_GPIO == GPIOD)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
    }
    else if(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].SERVO_GPIO == GPIOE)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
    }
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].SERVO_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].SERVO_GPIO, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /*--------[ Calculate The PSC & ARR Values To Maximize PWM Resolution ]-------*/

    /* Those Equations Sets The F_pwm = 50Hz & Maximizes The Resolution*/
    PSC_Value = (uint32_t) (SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].TIM_CLK / 3276800.0);
    ARR_Value = (uint32_t) ((SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].TIM_CLK / (50.0*(PSC_Value+1.0)))-1.0);

    /*--------[ Configure The Servo PWM Timer Channel ]-------*/

    /*--[Check The Timer & Enable Its Clock]--*/
    if(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].TIM_Instance == TIM1)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_TIM1_CLK_ENABLE();
    }
    else if(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].TIM_Instance == TIM2)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();
    }
    else if(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].TIM_Instance == TIM3)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_TIM3_CLK_ENABLE();
    }
    else if(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].TIM_Instance == TIM4)
    {
        __HAL_RCC_TIM4_CLK_ENABLE();
    }

    htim.Instance = SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].TIM_Instance;
    htim.Init.Prescaler = PSC_Value;
    htim.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim.Init.Period = ARR_Value;
    htim.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim);
    sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
    HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim, &sClockSourceConfig);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim);
    sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
    sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
    HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim, &sMasterConfig);
    sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
    sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
    sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
    HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim, &sConfigOC, SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].PWM_TIM_CH);

    /*--------[ Calculate & Save The Servo Pulse Information ]-------*/

    gs_SERVO_info[au16_SERVO_Instance].Period_Min = (uint16_t) (ARR_Value * (SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].MinPulse/20.0));
    gs_SERVO_info[au16_SERVO_Instance].Period_Max = (uint16_t) (ARR_Value * (SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].MaxPulse/20.0));

    /*--------[ Start The PWM Channel ]-------*/

    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim, SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].PWM_TIM_CH);
}
```

**Moving the servo**

```c
/* Moves A Specific Motor To A Specific Degree That Can Be Float Number */
void SERVO_MoveTo(uint16_t au16_SERVO_Instance, float af_Angle)
{
    uint16_t au16_Pulse = 0;

    au16_Pulse = ((af_Angle*(gs_SERVO_info[au16_SERVO_Instance].Period_Max - gs_SERVO_info[au16_SERVO_Instance].Period_Min))/180.0)
            + gs_SERVO_info[au16_SERVO_Instance].Period_Min;

    *(SERVO_CfgParam[au16_SERVO_Instance].TIM_CCRx) = au16_Pulse;
}
```

**GPIO and timer intitializations**

```
/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, LD1_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD2_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(USB_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, USB_PowerSwitchOn_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USER_Btn_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USER_Btn_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USER_Btn_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : RMII_MDC_Pin RMII_RXD0_Pin RMII_RXD1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RMII_MDC_Pin|RMII_RXD0_Pin|RMII_RXD1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF11_ETH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : RMII_REF_CLK_Pin RMII_MDIO_Pin RMII_CRS_DV_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RMII_REF_CLK_Pin|RMII_MDIO_Pin|RMII_CRS_DV_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF11_ETH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LD1_Pin LD3_Pin LD2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD1_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : RMII_TXD1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RMII_TXD1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF11_ETH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(RMII_TXD1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USB_PowerSwitchOn_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USB_PowerSwitchOn_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USB_PowerSwitchOn_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : USB_OverCurrent_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = USB_OverCurrent_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(USB_OverCurrent_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : RMII_TX_EN_Pin RMII_TXD0_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = RMII_TX_EN_Pin|RMII_TXD0_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF11_ETH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
  TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim1, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
  sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2State = TIM_BREAK2_DISABLE;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Polarity = TIM_BREAK2POLARITY_HIGH;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Filter = 0;
  sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim2);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM3 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 1 */
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3);

}

/**
  * @brief TIM4 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM4_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 1 */
  htim4.Instance = TIM4;
  htim4.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim4.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim4.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim4.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim4.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim4, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim4, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim4);

}
```

Let me know if there is any more information that you need.

Comment: Please try to add uint16_t type cast for au16_pulse variable in the SERVO_MoveTo function.

Comment: @recep I added this but it did solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be due to the alternate function mapping. The F767 datasheet has a table on p.89 listing what values you should put into the `GPIOn.AFR` registers (`GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate` in the HAL - I assume) to get the right peripheral on the pin. It looks like your timer channels for those pins are all `AF1`, and you haven't defined which AF to use in your `SERVO_Init` routine. It's probably a good idea to fill in every member of the struct, even if you think it's unnecessary, just to make sure you don't miss anything deceptively important.

Comment: I added in ```GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM1``` and the PWM signals began to generate but only after 1.3 minutes. I measured it several times and it is very consistient. Do you have any why this is happening?

Comment: Nothing sticks out. I was expecting to see some busy-waiting holding it up. Are you able to attach a debugger to this? Try setting a breakpoint on your `HAL_TIM_PWM_Start` line in your `SERVO_Init` function. If it takes 1.3 minutes to break, it's a code problem. If it gets there quickly, but still takes a minute thereafter until you see the waveform, it's likely a configuration or hardware problem.